# polygonOffset does not work in IE11?

Tags: three.js, internet-explorer-11

A simple z-fighting problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmchen/y03q54oa/

```
polygonOffset: true,
polygonOffsetFactor: 1.0,
polygonOffsetUnits: 4.0
```

Code works fine in latest Chrome, FF, even Edge, but in IE11 generates artifacts. My findings show, that in IE11, function polygonOffset changes Z-position of the mesh, not the depth buffor value!!! Can someone confirm my suspiction? Should I report bug in Microsoft or in THREEJS lib?

Comment: How did you figure out that it changes the z-position? This feature is a bit hard for me to understand, i always imagined that it could push the pixels by the smallest number the depth buffer can fit, but it doesn't seem like it works like that. I need to try this in ie11, but what happens when you crank the number up?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code. If your fiddle ever gets deleted, then the context of your question goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work in IE11 with the following:

```
var mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff,
        polygonOffset: true,
        polygonOffsetFactor: 0,
        polygonOffsetUnits: 0
}));
```

It seems to only happen when the two shapes are both meshes (the lines work fine). While it doesn't make much sense (every browser on Windows renders through ANGLE unless you force it into native GL mode), this is an IE problem.

I tested your original code in Edge, and it works fine. Microsoft has pretty much put IE to sleep, only producing security updates going forward.

Comment: see my answer. It seems this is not only IE11 specific, change in WebGLState.setPolygonOffset should resolve this problem without need of workaround (setting polygonOffset: true) in every material.

Comment: This did not work for me on IE11, Win7. What did work was adding `gl_Position.z -= 0.001;` to the vertex shader of mesh that should be "on top" (from the camera POV).

Comment: @ahwayakchih Strange, because my IE11 test was also on Win7. Your "magic number" workaround will work, but it may only work in your use-case. Keep that in mind the difference that `0.001` makes as you create meshes of different sizes in scenes of different depths.

Comment: @TheJim01 yes, of course you're right. I should have mentioned it. Still, just manipulating that number should help in case where `polygonOffset` does not.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is problem in WebGLState.setPolygonOffset function:

```
if ( polygonOffset ) {

        enable( gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL );

        if ( currentPolygonOffsetFactor !== factor || currentPolygonOffsetUnits !== units ) {

            gl.polygonOffset( factor, units );

            currentPolygonOffsetFactor = factor;
            currentPolygonOffsetUnits = units;

        }

    } else {

        disable( gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL );

    }
```

If there is one mesh with polygonOffset=true, library enables gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL. It seems, **in IE11, disabling this feature for other materials (polygonOffset=false) does not work properly**. And the rest of meshes use the same factor and units -> artifacts are visible. If you set for other meshes polygonOffset=true and default values factor, units = {0,0) as in your example  -> library sets new factor,units and everything is fine. I think, the function WebGLState.setPolygonOffset could be changed in order to set factor,units for every material, not only for polygonOffset=true, if there was at least one mesh with polygonOffset=true.

Regards
Waldemar

Comment: You should bring this up with the THREE.js developers. Create a bug report here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues and they can decide whether the issue warrants updating the method in their release.